# Facing issue with rest api

Tags: rest, magento

I Run Below Code For Add New Customer In Magento Using Rest API
Before Run I Will do login and Authorized But Also It Redirect From This Line :-  `$oauthClient->enableDebug();` and I am getting error - 404 Not Found Page

```
<?php
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/magento/webservices/NewCustomer1.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=". urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 's3xt7w8lwhfrrfzrfvwm3lrilkf66d5n';
$consumerSecret = 'vr3eq1x899pz1cf4zzxjzx3q03t66r3n';


session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/customers";
        $customerData = json_encode(array(
            'firstname'           => 'demofirstname',
            'lastname'            => 'demolastname',
            'email_address'       => 'demo@gmail.com',
            'password'            => 'demo1234',
            'confirmation'        => 'demo1234',

        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $customerData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: did u configure oAuth in your server? I mean, Do you have oAuth in your webserver?

Comment: yes i already do it first...